# Can't get cell automatic height to work

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm trying to retrieve images and then display them in a cell. The width of every image should be the same, but the height can vary - and therefore, I need the cell size to adjust automatically.

I do this to retrieve the image and scale it:

```
cell.thumbnail.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageURL), placeholderImage: blankImage)         
cell.thumbnail.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
```

and this to get the cell size to change dynamically:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
 }
```

But I can't get it to work!

The problems are:

1) The image appears super stretched out in height

2) I have to scroll past the image and then back to it just to see the ratio change

3) The scrolling is super glitchy (it's NOT because of the image load)

4) I have a segue from that leads from the cell to another view controller. Once I click on the cell, the entire table glitches for a second. When I got back to it, all the images are resized in a completely different way.

I set the constraints correctly so I know it's not a problem with that.

Comment: At looked at the constraints but I can't really see it, do you have a height constraint on the imageVew?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this as well:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem - I have to click the cell, then go back to the page just to see everything refresh. When it does, the height is all stretched

Comment: I would suggest rechecking your constraints and how your image is loaded then. I've used estimatedHeight and heightForRow to get automatic cell heights working. I've used it in 5-6 projects and never had any issues.

Answer (score 0):

When initializing table view do the following:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500 //Put just any approximate average height for cell. This will just be used to show scroll bar offset.
```

Remove the method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Tried that. Still getting the same problem. Here are my [constraints](http://s16.postimg.org/ffx57mr51/Screen_Shot_2015_04_14_at_10_35_34_PM.png) . Am I scaling the image correctly?